Why does my instantiate function have the incorrect position?
So, since I am a brand-new unity person that came back after 2 years I am trying to make Minecraft. But since I have forgot everything, I want to make the player spawn the chunk. So, whenever I press the letter c. It will instantiate the chunk spawner with no rotation and spawn at the player's position. Now this is where the problem comes. For some reason it is spawning at the game object that has this script and not the player. Here is how I Instantiated:
Instantiate(spawnPrefab, new Vector3(player.position.x, player.position.y, player.position.z), Quaternion.identity);

I do have a transform variable named player and I have assigned the player to it.
Here is the whole script.
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnChunk : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject spawnPrefab;
    public Transform player;

    private static SpawnChunk instance;
    private float spawnCooldown = 1.5f; 
    private float lastSpawnTime = -1f;

    void Update ()
    {
        if (Time.time >= lastSpawnTime + spawnCooldown && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            DuplicateChunk();
            lastSpawnTime = Time.time;
        }
    }

    void Awake ()
    {
        if (instance != null && instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            return;
        }
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }

    public void DuplicateChunk ()
    {
        if (spawnPrefab != null && player != null && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            Debug.Log("unity why do you have to make this so hard for me");
            Instantiate(spawnPrefab, new Vector3(player.position.x, player.position.y, player.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
        }
        else
        {
            if (spawnPrefab == null) Debug.LogError("****Spawn Prefab is null****");
            if (player == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("****Player is null****");
                player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
            }
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate ()
    {
        DuplicateChunk();
    }
}


So, when I encountered the issue. I was really confused because like I already assigned the players transform. So, I tried debugging. I put a Debug.Log() to print the player's position. It was saying the factual player's position. By that time, I already thought something was wrong with unity, so I looked into the script deeper, and I tried showing the position to unity differently. I tried making a vector3 and assigning that vector3 and did not work. I even made a new Vector3 and assigned the separate x, y and z values. Also did not work. I had one last solution. I tried also finding it from a tag. And can you guess it? It did not work.

well other than  you should just be able to send player.position not need to make a new vector from it, how is it wrong? is there any chance the player is not actually centered on the player

you do player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform; are you sure only the correct object is tagged? Are you also sue you didn't maybe reference the wrong object via the Inspector?

Note that during play mode you can simply click on the player variable in the inspector to see what object it references. Make sure your gizmo mode is set to "pivot" and "local", otherwise the gizmo you see will not be at the right place. Finally, does that spawnPrefab object has any script on it that may change the position of the object once it's spawned? Maybe add a script to the spawnPrefab that prints out it's own position in Start, so you can compare it with the position you used to spawn it. Are they really different?

Is the right object assigned to player?

This question comes from @GuardingPearSoftware since they dont have the reputation to coment on questions atm.
On which GameObject did you assign your SpawnChunk script? Is it also the Player GameObject?
Like the other said, most likely you attached the wrong GameObject to the Player Transform inside your script. Could you try logging your Player Transform Position inside your SpawnChunk Update Script? I think this should indicate the problem.

Welcome back to Unity. So I belive that I know the problem but I cant confirm it through comments since I dont have enough reputation to do so. If its somehow wrong I will make sure to update.
When you made the script you likly attached the prefab version of the player. The one from the editor section instead from the level scene. Which means that it will grab the vector3 position from the prefab instead of the current "live" one in scene. Since you likly have the prefab with the same or similar transforms as the gameobject that contains this script it appears like its spawning at the transform of the script.
The solution is to either use the prefab that appears in the level editor or have the player send its own transform to the script through a method.

I would recommend you to check if your prefab position is at 0, 0, 0.

On which GameObject did you assign your SpawnChunk script? Is it also the Player GameObject?
Like the other said, most likely you attached the wrong GameObject to the Player Transform inside your script. Could you try logging your Player Transform Position inside your SpawnChunk Update Script? I think this should indicate the problem.

Just posted your question as a comment.
